# Find smallest discrete logarithm, knowing some discrete logarithm.

Tags: number-theory

Discrete logarithm is a value $x$ that satisfy the equality $$a^x \mod m = b$$

Is there an easy way to find the smallest possible discrete logarithm, knowing some other discrete log. Basically if I have $x_1$ that satisfy the equality, is there a way to find $x_2$ that is the smallest possible?

Comment: Any assumptions about $a$? Such as primitivity? Or at least $\gcd(a,m)=1$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen it would be nice to know this in any case, but actually $gcd(a, m) = 1$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $a$ (equivalently, $b$) is coprime to $m$, $a^{x_1}\equiv a^{x_2}\pmod m$ implies $a^{x_1-x_2}\equiv 1\pmod m$, so $x_1-x_2$ is a multiple of the order $o(a)$ of $a$ modulo $m$. And vice versa, $x_1\equiv x_2\pmod{o(a)}$ implies $a^{x_2}\equiv a^{x_1}$. So we should take $x_2=x_1\bmod {o(a)}$. Remains to find $o(a)$. Certainly, $o(a)\mid \varphi(m)$ as $a^{\varphi(m)}\equiv 1\pmod m$. Starting from $o:=\varphi(m)$, try all primes $p\mid o$ and check whether $a^{o/p}\equiv 1\pmod m$ and if so, replace $o$ with $o/p$ and start again.

$\varphi(m)$ is an [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

Comment: Just one small point. Finding the order of $a$ will in general be about as hard as factoring a number of length $\log(m)$.

Comment: just to be sure: is ϕ(m) a totient function?